# obtaining solutions to an ode after solving for $y'$. Can one just verify the solutions to the ode's generated and not to the original ode?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

sometimes when an ode is non-linear in $y'$, I first solve for $y'$ in order to be able to solve the ode. This is if in its original form, there is no obvious way to solve it as is.

This ends up generating more (but simpler odes') when doing this (i.e. roots of the equation).

These simpler odes are then solved, each generating its own solution. But the solutions they generate, more time than not, do not verify the original ode.

My question is: Is it Mathematically correct to just verify the solutions to each simpler ode against itself and not against the original (parent) ode, and if each is verified, to stop here and say these are the solutions to the original ode?

In this example below, I could not validate the solutions against the original ode. But only against the simpler odes.

Otherwise, I have no idea what to do if I can't simplify the original ode by solving for $y'$. I give below a diagram to help explain also.

Let say the original ode is
$$
\sqrt{y'} + y' + x =0
$$

If it is not clear how to solve this directly, then solving for $y'$ gives the two odes

\begin{align*}
y' &= -x +\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{-4 x +1}}{2} \\\\
y' &=-x +\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{-4 x +1}}{2}
\end{align*}

Now each ode is easy to solve for. The solutions are

\begin{align*}
y_1(x) &= -\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{\left(-4 x +1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{12}+\frac{x}{2}+c_1\\\\
y_2(x) &=-\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{\left(-4 x +1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{12}+\frac{x}{2}+c_1
\end{align*}

Can one stop here and say these solutions are the solution to the original ode? (Verified they are correct solutions to the simplified ones, but could not verify against the original ode).

[image]

Comment: By squaring an equation you also add the variant where the sides of the equation have opposite sign. This is then obviously not a solution of the original equation. So you have to check the solution against the original equation, including all implied constraints like $y'\ge 0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thanks, You are right. One of these solutions verifies the original ODE under the condition that $x\leq 0$. But the other does not verify the original ode for any $x$. Maple and Mathematica give both solutions I show. So they must did the same thing (i.e. solve for $y'$ first). But they do not tell the user which of the solutions is the correct one for the original ode, and under what conditions, that is why I asked., The bottom line then, you think the final solution should verify the original ode, and not just the derived ones. That is what I thought also. Just wanted to check.

Comment: Mathematica at least considers equations by default over the complex domain. There the square root is not a function but a solution of the defining equation, which gives two branches. So it effectively solves $y'=u^2$, $u+u^2+x=0$, which finds both variants as valid solutions. The restriction to the real domain can be enforced, but I do not know the details and whether WolframAlpha supports it.

Answer (score 1):

It can be verified. It suffices to work with $y_1'$ and $y_2'$ since the given ODE is in $y'$. I shall do it for the case for $y_1$.

$$y_1'(x) = -x + \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{-4x+1}}{2}$$
by differentiating $y_1(x)$ that you have obtained, or basically just reading off the original ODE to be solved. Then, note that

$$-x+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{-4x+1}}{2} = \left(\frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{1-4x}) \right)^2$$
which is something you would have noticed if you solve the quadratic equation in $\sqrt{y'}$ by hand, as this $y_1'$ is obtained by squaring $\sqrt{y_1'} = \frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{1-4x})$ on both sides. Then, we check that

$$\begin{aligned} \sqrt{y_1'} &=  \frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{1-4x}) = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-4x} \\ y_1' &= -x + \frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-4x+1} \\
\therefore \text{we have } \sqrt{y_1'} + y_1' + x &= - x + x = 0. \end{aligned}$$

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding here.  You seem to have verified the solution of one of the _simpler_ odes against the simpler ode. I know these solution are correct. The question was __if__ these solutions need to be verified against the original ode as well. As that is the much harder problem. And to find the domain if any where these solutions satisfy the original ode.

Comment: If you are concerned with the relevant domains, you can first plot the relevant graphs $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ for $x \in (-\infty,1/4)$, and see that $y_1'(x) \geq 0$ and $y_2'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ in that domain (in fact, from your solution, you can prove that $y_2'(x) \geq 1/4$). These are thus valid solutions to your given nonlinear ODE. Indeed, plotting $\neq$ proving, but this gives you an intuition that it is at least correct before going on to prove that these are indeed the solution.

Comment: Following Lutz Lehmann's comment, you will have to check if these indeed satisfy the original ODE, and a simple plug-and-play would not work all the time - you will have to combine some graphical insights/analytical insights to prove that they indeed satisfy the ODE (I guess that will answer your question instead then).